# Get the sum of rows that contain 0 as a value

Tags: python

I want to know how can I make the source code of the following problem based on Python.

I have a dataframe that contain this column:

```
Column X
1
0
0
0
1
1
0
0
1
```

I want to create a list b counting the sum of successive 0 value for getting something like that :

```
List X
1
3
3
3
1
1
2
2
1
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It is unclear what you want.

Comment: I have a column of numbers that contain many values, I want to create a list like this: when I find "1" in the old column I keep it ( newdata.append(1)) but when I find 0 I should count all the successive row that contains 0 and I should put on them the max value i.e. if I found 3 successive rows containing 0 I must Add 3 row in the list, all of them have 3 as value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to replace all the zeros with the number of consecutive zeros in the current streak, but leave non-zero numbers untouched. So

```
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

becomes

```
1 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 5
```

To do that, this should work, assuming your input column (a pandas Series) is called `x`.

```py
result = []
i = 0
while i < len(x):
    if x[i] != 0:
        result.append(x[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        # See how many times zero occurs in a row
        j = i
        n_zeros = 0
        while j < len(x) and x[j] == 0:
            n_zeros += 1
            j += 1
        result.extend([n_zeros] * n_zeros)
        i += n_zeros
result
```

*Adding screenshot below to make usage clearer*
[image: Screenshot]